# I've got a new Lenovo Yoga Pro 7 14APH8 and after grub bootloader screen I'm seeing amdgpu firmware failed to load messages. How could i solve this?

Tags: debian, boot, gnome, firmware, amdgpu

I installed Debian 12 Bookworm with Gnome on my new Yoga notebook (Ryzen 7 7840HS with Radeon™ 780M), and I'm getting strange amdgpu error while booting.

This is my `dmesg | grep 'firmware'` output:

```
[    0.053111] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    1.896309] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: failed to load amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes_2.bin (-2)
[    1.896357] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[    1.896394] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: failed to load amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes_2.bin (-2)
[    1.896420] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: Direct firmware load for amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes_2.bin failed with error -2
[    1.896464] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes.bin
[    1.896499] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mes1.bin
[    1.897445] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/psp_13_0_4_toc.bin
[    1.897487] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/psp_13_0_4_ta.bin
[    1.897621] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/dcn_3_1_4_dmcub.bin
[    1.897624] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x08000500
[    1.897657] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_imu.bin
[    1.897693] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_pfp.bin
[    1.897725] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_me.bin
[    1.897746] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_rlc.bin
[    1.897779] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/gc_11_0_1_mec.bin
[    1.898313] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/sdma_6_0_1.bin
[    1.898366] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/vcn_4_0_2.bin
[    1.898367] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.10 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 0
[    1.898373] amdgpu 0000:63:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    4.531269] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
[    4.531359] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
[    4.701149] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware mediatek/WIFI_MT7922_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin
[    4.716652] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware mediatek/WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin
[    4.766133] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware mediatek/WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin
[    5.508199] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware mediatek/BT_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1_1_hdr.bin
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me with this.

Comment: Third line. Have you done what it says?

Answer (score 0):

Debian's amdgpu firmware package even in Sid (experimental bleeding edge version of Debian) is terribly outdated: https://packages.debian.org/sid/firmware-amd-graphics it's from 2023-06-25.

I'd recommend doing this:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/
cd linux-firmware
sudo cp -a --no-preserve=ownership amdgpu /lib/firmware
```

And reboot.